# Visual Studio 2015 does not have menu "Target framework"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS2015 with version 14.0.25123.00 Update2.  I create HelloWorld for Windows Phone project.  I right-click on the project to go into project Properties.  Then I see tabs: Application, Build, Build Events, Debug, Reference Paths, Signing, and Code Analysis.  In the Application tab, I don't see "Target framework:" drop-down box.  I would like to change the .NET Framework version, but there is no menu to change.  Am I missing something?  thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone projects do not have that and it is by design. You have only the Windows Phone runtime to target and no others.

Comment: then do you know where I can change the .NET framework version?

Comment: @PhillipC, for what version you want to change to? Windows Phone only has a single version, which is why nobody gives you a way to change it.

Comment: actually I also tried on non-Windows Phone project, I still don't see the "Target framework" menu like this instruction from Microsoft site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: @PhillipC then show a screen shot. If you use the Express edition, or you create another type of project that only has a single version related, that menu won't appear either.

Comment: ok sure.  Let me paste a screen shot.  I never paste screen shots before in Stackoverflow so will try,

Comment: I just uploaded the screen shot in the original post.  thanks.

Comment: @PhillipC yes, just another project type that only targets Windows 8.1 which has a single framework to target and no way to switch. Can you simply create a class library to play first?

Comment: I create a new Windows Phone library project and attach the screen shot above, but it's still the same result.

Comment: @PhillipC you can only create a normal class library/console/WinForms/ASP.NET project to see that menu. All phone/UWP related project types won't give you that.

Comment: Lex Li, thanks alot for answering my questions.  very appreciate.